# Named pipe connection with JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I was able to make a ODBC connections with the following DSN file:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=SQL Server
UID=username
Network=networkName
DATABASE=dbName
WSID=workstationName
APP=Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
SERVER=serverName
Description=Sandbox
```

My jdbc conn string looks like:

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://Protocol=pipe;Server=serverName;path=sameAsServerName;Database=dbName;Uid=userName;Pwd=password\r\n"
```

but I am still getting the unable to connect to TCP/IP port 1433. ODBC connected using named pipes.

Comment: Which driver are you using, and have you verified that it indeed supports named pipe connections?

Comment: I am using Microsoft jdbc 8.2. I dont know if it supports named pipe connections but am looking now

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the Microsoft driver doesn't support named pipes, if you really need that, you should look for the jTDS driver (though I'm not sure how compatible that is with recent SQL Server versions).